# Special characters in WCF REST post method?

Tags: wcf

Sometimes I am getting error `400 bad request` when sending special characters, like '&', etc. Like the characters in XML format to the REST WCF method.

What is the reason and why am I getting this error? Which characters doesn't support the XML format request to the REST WCF post method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) we can pass all characters.

Syntax:

```
<![CDATA[ Tax = 8 & of Subtotal ]]>
```